# Change textview color from an array of textviews

Tags: android, arrays, android-fragments, butterknife

I am using textviews as a list, on click of each textview a fragment opens.
I want to change the background of textview and its color when its clicked.
Onclick of another textview, the previous background color and text color should change to its default color. I am using Butterknife to bind all the textviews into an array.

Here is my code :

```
public class AccountMenuFragment extends Fragment {

private accountMenuCallback callback;
private boolean stateChanged;

public AccountMenuFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    try {
        callback = (accountMenuCallback) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ClassCastException("Calling Activity/Fragment must implement DialogClickListener interface");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@OnClick({R.id.rlAccount, R.id.rlBusiness, R.id.rlIndustry,
        R.id.rlVerification, R.id.rlBank, R.id.rlPersonal, R.id.rlPassword})
public void changeColor(TextView textView) {
    stateChanged = !stateChanged;
    if (stateChanged) {
        // reset background to default;
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
    }
}}
```

But it changes its color on double click of the same textview. But I want to change and restore the previous on a single click.

Comment: `private boolean stateChanged = !stateChanged;` what are you doing here? A `private` variable inside a method? does that even compile?

Comment: private boolean stateChanged; is a globally declared variable

Comment: you have to use that variable using `this.varabaleName` in the method if same name variable is there..........

Comment: if u are using butterknife check "VIEW LISTS" option described in the site http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: @sushildlh No. It's still the same.

Comment: use this `private boolean stateChanged = !this.stateChanged;`  instead of this  `private boolean stateChanged = !stateChanged;` and let me know its working

Comment: @sushildlh : It does'nt work. I have to click the textview twice so that it changes its color, but all the textviews change the color,

Comment: will you please post whole activity , so we can get some idea about your mistake .....

Comment: @sushildlh : You can now check the full code

Comment: how many textView are there ??

Comment: @sushildlh : There are 7 textviews. On each textview clicked, a new fragment opens. Its designed for a Tablet app.

Answer (score 0):

Set the first view as selected by default and declare it as lastSelectedView.

```
public class AccountMenuFragment extends Fragment {

private accountMenuCallback callback;
@Bind(R.id.rlAccount)
TextView lastSelectedView;

public AccountMenuFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    try {
        callback = (accountMenuCallback) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ClassCastException("Calling Activity/Fragment must implement DialogClickListener interface");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@OnClick({R.id.rlAccount, R.id.rlBusiness, R.id.rlIndustry,R.id.rlVerification, R.id.rlBank, R.id.rlPersonal, R.id.rlPassword})
public void changeColorOfTextView(TextView textView) {
   // reset background to default;
   lastSelectedView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
   lastSelectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

   // change color
   textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
   textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
   lastSelectedView = textView;
}}
```